Fastest way to Split Large XML File -57000 records, 4 million lines using PowerShell script
I'm running a script on PowerShell to split a 115MB XML file. It contains over 50,000 records, and the lines go up to 4 million when opened on notepad++. Each record contains several nodes, one of which has an amount figure.
The footer in the file sums the total number of records and the total amounts read from each record. I haven't added this footer check yet, as I'm still struggling to split the files as proof of concept. In my last three attempts, the script ran for more than 18hrs, and I've had to terminate without any successful result. What's the fastest way to get this running? Here is my script:
$limit = 10000
$logpath = "C:\Users\K_iduli\Downloads\ABC_Documents_CREATE_FINRECORD_20240912_3.xml"
[xml]$xml="<DocList>$(Get-Content $logpath)</DocList>"
$index = 1
$ref = new-object xml
$rows = $xml.SelectNodes("//Doc")
$c = $rows.count
$rows | %{
    if($index -eq 1){
        [xml]$insertNode = @"
<DocList><a></a></DocList>
"@
     $ref.AppendChild($ref.ImportNode($InsertNode.DocumentElement, $false))
    }
    $ref.DocumentElement.AppendChild($ref.ImportNode($_,$true))
    $c--
    if($index -eq $limit){
        $index = 1
        $ref.Save("C:\Users\K_iduli\Downloads\Test\ABC_Documents_CREATE_FINRECORD_20240912_{0:D6}.xml" -f ++$i)
        $ref = new-object xml
        if($c -lt $limit){$limit = $c}
    }
    else{
      $index++;
    }
}


I expected my script to create up to six files in the location C:\Users\K_iduli\Downloads\Test\ABC_Documents_CREATE_FINRECORD_20240912, however, the folder remains empty, and the process hasn't been successful.

I wouldn't use Powershell. I'd use something that involves Xpath - either with Python or Java. https://devhints.io/xpath

Also is your XML well formed.. Does it have an XSD or DTD at the top.

Have you done any profiling to see what part of the code takes the most time?

As an aside, it looks like you might have a bug if the number of records isn’t an exact multiple of your batch size - the last incomplete batch wouldn’t get saved in that case…

Also, what is the format of the input file? You’re wrapping it in a <DocList> element which makes me think you’ve got multiple xml documents concatenated in your source file - it might be faster to split them and process individually…

Power shell can become extremely slow when handling large numbers of objects. You might find it faster to parse the file as text and split it up based on the tags. It would help us if you posted some sample data.

Well, I don't know about it being the fastest possible, but it should be very easy to beat 18 hours, which is ridiculous. I haven't tried to reverse-engineer your requirements from your code, but an XSLT 2.0+ stylesheet that does
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 200">
    <xsl:result-document href="out{position()}.xml">
       <batch>
         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
       </batch>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform> 

should run in under 10 seconds. If the size gets into the gigabyte range you can reduce the memory requirement by running it under an XSLT 3.0 processor that supports streaming. For simple streaming transformations I generally use a first-cut estimate of 1 minute per gigabyte, but it can sometimes be a lot faster.

For huge xml files use code like this in PS
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$FILENAME = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($FILENAME)
while($reader.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if ($reader.Name -ne "Employee")
   {
      $reader.ReadToFollowing("Employee")
   }
   if ($reader.EOF -eq $False)
   {
       $employee = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
       $id = $employee.Attribute("id").Value 
       $fname = $employee.Element("FName").Value
       $lname = $employee.Element("LName").Value 
       $city = $employee.Element("City").Value 
       #Write-Output "id = $id first = $fname last = $lname city = $city"
   }
}


Thank you, guys, for the comments. I opted to use Python. And even though I haven't had much experience with Python, I got a successful result from a script I appropriated from google search. I got 5 split files from running the sript. Will definitely be relying on Python for such jobs in future.
 with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    first_line = file.readline()
    second_line = file.readline()
    header = f"{first_line}{second_line}"
    file_number = 1
    size = 0
    lines_buffer = []

    for line in file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        lines_buffer.append(line)
        size += len(line.encode('utf-8'))

        # Check if we should write the current buffer to a file
        if size > size_limit and last_element_close in stripped_line:
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{output_file_prefix}_{file_number}.xml")
            with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
                out_file.write(header)
                out_file.writelines(lines_buffer)  # Write all buffered lines
                out_file.write(last_element_close)  # Close the XML properly
            print(f"Wrote file {file_number}: {output_file}")

            file_number += 1
            size = 0
            lines_buffer = []

    # Write any remaining records to the last file
    if lines_buffer:
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"{output_file_prefix}_{file_number}.xml")
        with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
            out_file.write(header)
            out_file.writelines(lines_buffer)
            out_file.write(last_element_close)  # Close the XML properly
        print(f"Wrote final file {file_number}: {output_file}")


Reading an XML file, as if it only contains text, is not a good option. ( 'not' as in never)

@MichaelKay provided you with the best possible answer. Additionally, XSLT 3.0 has snapshot() function exactly for your scenario. Just call XSLT transformation from Python, or any other language.
